# Computing $\iiint_\mathbb{R^3} e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}dxdydz$ using substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider this integral:
$$\iiint_\mathbb{R^3} e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}dxdydz$$
How would you compute it?

---

I already solved this problem this way:
$$\iiint_\mathbb{R^3} e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}dxdydz = \left( \int_\infty^\infty e^{-x^2} \right)^3 = \pi^{3/2}$$

But I wanted to find it using substitution (spherical coordinates) but this is all I could do:
$$\iiint_\mathbb{R^3} e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}dxdydz = \lim_{j\,\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^jdu\int_0^\pi dv\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-u^2}u^2\sin(v) dw=$$

$$=2\pi\lim_{j\,\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^jdu\int_0^\pi e^{-u^2}u^2\sin(v)dv=4\pi\lim_{j\,\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^je^{-u^2}u^2du$$

But it doesn't get me anywhere. Help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be $e^{-u^2}$.  The integrals over $v$ and $w$ produce a factor of $4 \pi$.

Comment: Yes, I changed the $e^{u^2}$ into $e^{-u^2}$, but the factor $4\pi$ was there from the beginning unless you I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish off your problem, you only need

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}x^2dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$

which can be shown by integrating

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

by parts.  That is, we have:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=xe^{-x^2}\vert_{0}^{\infty}+2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}x^2dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}x^2dx$$

Comment: Very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}x^2dx = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\infty } e^{-x^2} x \;  2x dx = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\infty } e^{-u} \sqrt u du = \frac{\Gamma (3/2)}{2} = \frac 1 4\sqrt{\pi}$$